# Using ng-template outside the scope

Tags: angular

I have a requirement of creating recursive menu where data is coming from JSON, whose structure is like this:

```
 this.menus = [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Azure",
        "class": "fa-cloud",
        "url": "#",
        "menu": [{
          "id": 121,
          "title": "Azure AD",
          "class": "fa-cloud",
          "url": "#",
          "menu": [{
            "id": 1210,
            "title": "Settings",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#",
            "menu": [{
              "id": 1210,
              "title": "Apps",
              "class": "fa-cloud",
              "url": "#",
              "menu": [{
                "id": 2210,
                "title": "Apps2",
                "class": "fa-cloud",
                "url": "#",
              }]
            }, {
              "id": 1211,
              "title": "Users",
              "class": "fa-cloud",
              "url": "#"
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "AWS",
        "class": "fa-cloud",
        "url": "#",
        "menu": [{
          "id": 21,
          "title": "DMS",
          "class": "fa-cloud",
          "url": "#",
          "menu": [{
            "id": 211,
            "title": "End Points",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#"
          }, {
            "id": 2112,
            "title": "Replication",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#"
          },
          {
            "id": 2112,
            "title": "Replication3",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#"
          },
          {
            "id": 2112,
            "title": "Replication4",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#"
          },
          {
            "id": 2112,
            "title": "Replication5",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#"
          }]
        }]
      },
      {"id": 2,
    "title": "AWS2",
    "class": "fa-cloud",
    "url": "#",
    "menu": [{
            "id": 211,
            "title": "rr1",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#"
          }, {
            "id": 2112,
            "title": "rr2",
            "class": "fa-cloud",
            "url": "#"
          }]
      },
      {"id": 2,
      "title": "AWS3",
      "class": "fa-cloud",
      "url": "#",
      "menu": [{
              "id": 211,
              "title": "aws3-rr1",
              "class": "fa-cloud",
              "url": "#"
            }, {
              "id": 2112,
              "title": "aws3-rr2",
              "class": "fa-cloud",
              "url": "#"
            }]
        },
        {"id": 2,
        "title": "AWS4",
        "class": "fa-cloud",
        "url": "#",
        "menu": [{
                "id": 211,
                "title": "AWS4-rr1",
                "class": "fa-cloud",
                "url": "#"
              }, {
                "id": 2112,
                "title": "AWS4-rr2",
                "class": "fa-cloud",
                "url": "#"
              }]
          },
          {"id": 2,
        "title": "AWS5",
        "class": "fa-cloud",
        "url": "#",
        "menu": [{
                "id": 211,
                "title": "AWS5-rr1",
                "class": "fa-cloud",
                "url": "#"
              }, {
                "id": 2112,
                "title": "AWS5-rr2",
                "class": "fa-cloud",
                "url": "#"
              }]
          }
        ];
```

And there can be n number of child nodes, or submenu values, which should be visible on click of the parent menu, but this submenu node should come after 4 menu items. So if I have menus like : 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F', 'G', 'H' - and if I click on 'A', then the submenu A1 shoukd come in a div between First row of 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and second row of 'E','F', 'G', 'H'. I am able to cluster the json into 4 mnus each, but the issue is that I can only show submenu result inside its parent menu - So 'A1' submenu is shown inside 'A', 'B1' submenu is shown inside 'B'. This is because my ng-template is only recognized inside the div for ngFor, not ouside it.

HTML:

```
<ng-template #recursiveMenu let-menu_copy>
    <div *ngFor="let t of temp(math.ceil(menu_copy.length/4)).fill(); let i = index" class="col-md-12 dd">
  <div *ngFor="let menu of menu_copy.slice(4*i,4*i + 4); let i = index" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" >
     <a  title="{{menu.title}}" (click)="getMenuVal(menu,i,$event); menu.selected = !menu.selected;"
      data-target="#nav{{menu.id}}" >
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-2x {{menu.class}}"></i> <span class="nav-header-primary">{{menu.title}}</span> &nbsp;                
      <span *ngIf="menu.menu" class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x pull-right">                
      </span>  
    </a> 
    <ng-template #rSubMenu let-menu.menu>
    <ul class="nav collapse" style="margin-left:20px" *ngIf="menu.menu" id="nav{{menu.id}}" [ngClass]="{'in':menu.selected}">               
        <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenu; context:{ $implicit: menu.menu }"></ng-container>
    </ul>  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rSubMenu; context:{$implicit:menu_copy}" ></ng-container> </div>
  <div class="nav collapse" [ngClass]="{'in':getMenuValue.selected}">


</div>
 <div >

  </div>

</div> <!--dd ends-->

</ng-template>  

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <nav class="navbar">
           <div class="nav">           
             <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenu; context:{ $implicit: menu_copy }">
 </ng-container>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I would appreciate any help. A similar stackblitz [example is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9pvxs).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and make a recursion of it

**menu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() menues = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menues">
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{menu.title}}
            <app-menu [menues]="menu.menu" *ngIf="menu.menu"></app-menu>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-menu [menues]="menues"></app-menu>
```

You can check the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-recursion)

You can check [this](https://netbasal.com/recursion-in-angular-components-1cd636269b12) for more info.